# Display Full name instead of username in php

Tags: php, session-variables

I have a login table containing `Name`, `Username` and `Password`. When user logins with username and password, I want to display the name of the user instead of the username. I want to display user's name in the next page as *Welcome NAME* instead of *Welcome USERNAME*.

Here is the HTML:

```
<form class="form-basic" method="post" action="login.php">
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>
            <span>Username</span>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" >
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <label>
            <span>Password</span>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" >
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>SUBMIT</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

// your values are stored in cookies, then you can login without validate
include_once 'db.php';

// login validation in php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['username']));
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = mysql_query("select name,username,password from reglogin where username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'");

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if ($numrows != 0) {
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $dbname=$row['username'];
            $dbpassword=$row['password'];
        }

       if($username == $dbname &&  $password == $dbpassword)
       {
           $_SESSION['sess_user']=$name;
            echo "<script>window.open('registration1.php','_self')</script>";
        }   
    }
    else {
       echo "<script>alert('Invalid! Username or Password')</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Show the code where you display the name

Comment: After user login with username and password if login is correct it goes to registration1.php page where it will display as <h4 ><b>Welcome <?=$_SESSION['name']?>

Comment: what `var_dump($_SESSION['name']);` return and `var_dump($name);`

Comment: It doesnt display anything. Session variable doesnt display anything

Comment: use $_SESSION['sess_user'] insead of  $_SESSION['name'].you have set the session name as "sess_user" not "name"

Comment: And make sure that you have `session_start();` at the top

Comment: I have add seesion_start() as well as changed $_SESSION['sess_user']. It display error undefined variable name.

Comment: @user6582683.you have error in $name=$_POST['name']; .check my answer

Comment: where in HTML you are using the input for 'name'??

Comment: I want to fetch the name from database when username and password is selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your code with this one:
**Your errors:**

1. In the line number 8 you have an Undefined Index called name.
2. You are using that in value for $_SESSION which you can get from
   database while fetching the username and password.

Review your query what you are selecting and what you fetched.
**Changes I have made:**

1. check line number 8.
2. check line number 20

Hope this will help you.

```
// your values are stored in cookies, then you can login without validate
include_once 'db.php';

// login validation in php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // $name = $_POST['name'];   // this is not posted 
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['username']));
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = mysql_query("select name,username,password from reglogin where username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'");

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if ($numrows != 0) {
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $dbname=$row['username'];
            $dbpassword=$row['password'];
            $name =$row['name'];
        }

       if($username == $dbname &&  $password == $dbpassword)
       {
           $_SESSION['sess_user']=$name;
            echo "<script>window.open('registration1.php','_self')</script>";
        }   
    }
    else {
       echo "<script>alert('Invalid! Username or Password')</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have input

```
 <input type="text" name="username" id="username" >
```

In php side you are accessing

```
  $name=$_POST['name'];
```

you have to change above line to

```
 $name=$_POST['username'];
```

or you have to update

```
$_SESSION['sess_user']=$name;
```

to

```
$_SESSION['sess_user']=$row['username'];
```

**Updated**

As you need name so you can set name to session

```
$_SESSION['sess_user']=$row['name'];
```

Comment: $_SESSION['sess_user']=$row['username']; It will display the username which is used. I want to display the Name of user instead of username. If the Name of the user is ABC and username is ABC12 I want to display as Welcome ABC instead of Welcome ABC12